# Xcode Phonegap app path name

Tags: ios, cordova

There is something wrong with my app, when I ask the user whether to accept the geolocation you see the prompt looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJaQX.jpg

[image]

How can I escape this so that the app name appear instead of the path?
i get this message both in simulator and on iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the [Cordova Geolocation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation) should fix this, and replace that URL with the name of your app.

Comment: Still same problem..., do u know any other solution?

Comment: Can you post your geolocation code and does the call happen after the deviceready event has fired?

Comment: Problem solved! the problem was that geolocation went running before the device ready